# Google Fit API request returning empty points for steps (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, google-fit-api

Im following a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-yH1ZnZBWyU) on how to use the google fit API for checking steps with node.js and managed to make everything work.

My problem is, when getting the value of steps, the `point`array is returning empty.

## Examples

Here are some examples on what is happening vs. what should happen.

### my Request

```
    const result = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        authorization: "Bearer " + tokens.tokens.access_token
      },
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      url: `https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate`,
      data: {
        aggregateBy: [{
          dsataTypeName: "com.google.step_count.delta",
          dataSourceId: 'derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps'
        }],
        bucketByTime: { durationMillis: 1000*60*60*24 },
        startTimeMillis: 1642129199000, //get from https://currentmillis.com
        endTimeMillis: 1642301999000
      }
    })
```

This result will return to me a data.bucket with the data im looking for. However, those buckets are looking like this:

[image: my code]

When they should be looking like this (from the tutorial):

[image: image from the tutorial]

As you can see, my point array is empty rather then having some value.

I checked my Google fit App and I have data for this timespan.

Also noting that, even if I had taken 0 steps those days, the point array would not be empty, but would have value of 0.

Here is also the structure of the point array (also from tutorial):

[image: structure of the point array]

Is there something I'm missing thats dumb?? pls help I never coded for Google APIs before